# What does "$f$ is a function of $x$" mean?

Tags: functions, terminology, definition, elementary-functions

Rigorously speaking, a function $f: X \to Y$ is a mapping that maps each element from set $X$ to an element in set $Y$. (Or more rigorously it can be defined using cartesian product).
For $x \in X$, people often say $f$ is a function of $x$. What does that mean？Isn't $x$ just an element in $X$ and functions (in my understanding) are meant to be dealing with the entire set $X$.

Comment: Context matters.  In practice, one often has situations in which there are many independent variables and a given measurement may depend on some of those, but not on others.

Comment: @lulu Sorry but how does that relate to my question?

Comment: Well, if $x,y,z$ are independent variables then it has great meaning to say that , e.g., $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ but not of $z$.  Like I say, context matters.

Comment: @lulu I think you misunderstood my question. My question is about what does $f$ is a function of $x$ means when the definition of function only involves the mapping of sets not a specific value $x$.

Comment: In my opinion:

> "$f$ is a function of $x$"

Is simultaneously a terrible and useful thing to say, for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: I will give an example of a situation where this kind of terminology is usually used. Let $F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ and suppose we are asked to find its partial derivatives with respect to "y". In such situations we will say "f is a function of x" to indicate that we can treat it as constant while differentiating with respect to "y".

Answer (score 4):

In the expression "$f$ is a function of $x$" a lot is left unsaid.

What that usually means is that "$x$" is the name for a "typical" element of the domain, which may or may not be explicitly specified and may or may not be called "$X$".

In some context you might say "pressure $P$ is a function of temperature $T$" when dealing with the physics of the gas law
$$
PV = nRT .
$$

Answer (score 0):

The complete statement would be "$f$ is a function of $x\in X$". This literally means that
$$f\colon X \to ?, $$
where $?$ has not been specified. Often, it is obvious from context that $x\in X$, hence the abbreviated version "$f$ is a function of $x$".